# Is torch.empty_like() dependent on the input value as well as input size?

Tags: python, pytorch

The description in the torch docs for [torch.empty_like](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.empty_like.html#torch.empty_like) says:

> torch.empty_like(input, *, dtype=None, layout=None, device=None, requires_grad=False, memory_format=torch.preserve_format) → Tensor
>
> Returns an uninitialized tensor with the same size as input. `torch.empty_like(input)` is equivalent to `torch.empty(input.size(), dtype=input.dtype, layout=input.layout, device=input.device)`.
>
> Parameters
> input (Tensor) – the size of input will determine size of the output tensor.

What I do is :

```
>>> torch.empty(3,4)
tensor([[-1.8597e+15,  4.5657e-41, -1.8597e+15,  4.5657e-41],
        [ 4.4842e-44,  0.0000e+00,  8.9683e-44,  0.0000e+00],
        [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00]])

>>> c1
tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

>>> torch.empty_like(c1)
tensor([[139942262173040,  93851872482144,               1,               0],
        [              0,               0,  93851872492496,               0],
        [              0,               0,               0,               0]])

>>> d
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0.]])

>>> torch.empty_like(d)
tensor([[-8.6092e-25,  3.0620e-41,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00],
        [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00],
        [ 0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00]])
```

It seems that the tensor returned by `torch.empty_like` depends on input value, contrary to the description in the docs. Can someone explain this?

Comment: The contents of uninitialized memory could be absolutely anything.  `.empty_like()` is only useful in cases where you will immediately be assigning some value to all of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

The docs description is correct. I am not sure if you are confused by `torch.empty_like` returning different outputs on different calls, but you can see this is also the behaviour of `torch.empty` by calling e.g. `torch.empty((2,3), dtype=torch.int64)` multiple times.

Note `torch.empty_like` **does** depend on the `dtype` of the input (but not its specific values).